# layout-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modernizr

I'm writing angular program.
I use angular and http://materializecss.com/

This console logs:

```
layout-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 layout-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 flex-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 flex-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 layout-align-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 layout-align-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 flex-order-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 flex-order-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 flex-offset-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 flex-offset-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 hide-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `hide-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 hide-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `hide-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 show-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `show-gt-<xxx>` variant.
angular.js:13424 show-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `show-gt-<xxx>` variant.
```

I'm not using layout of angular.

How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm also getting same warnings while using angular material.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, they've been deprecated.

Are you using angular-material? They're the options provided by angular-material. If you're using angular-material, see: https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0-rc4/layout/options

Or if you're using materialize as you mentioned, just use classes from Materialize. See: http://materializecss.com/helpers.html