# Angular Material initialize with lots of warning msgs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm kind of new to AngularMaterial and trying to running up an application with `AngularJs v1.5.5` and `AngularMaterial v1.1.0-rc.5`
But i got lots of warning messages in app initialize:

```
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 layout-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 layout-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 flex-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 flex-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 layout-align-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 layout-align-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `layout-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 flex-order-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 flex-order-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 flex-offset-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 flex-offset-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `flex-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 hide-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `hide-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 hide-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `hide-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 show-lt-mdhas been deprecated. Please use a `show-gt-<xxx>` variant.
mainScripts?v=VXgz:1 show-lt-lghas been deprecated. Please use a `show-gt-<xxx>` variant.
```

And these are the files i'm loading:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mainScripts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-aria.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular-material.js",
    "~/Scripts/underscore.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/ADM-dateTimePicker.min.js"
));
```

My project is empty! what is it all about?

Comment: According to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/36463343/782358 - they look like errors thrown by Angular Materialize (http://materializecss.com/). Are you using/loading it anywhere? mainScripts, perhaps.

Comment: @MeTe-30: Did you find any solution for this? I'm also getting same warnings while using angular material.